# Access Denied when using Access ODBC Driver

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2017, openrowset

When using Access 2016 ODBC driver to open an excel document, I get Access Denied in ProcMon. I only get this on error a file on a remote file share.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 'Excel 12.0; DATABASE=\\servername\path\to\file.xls', [PAGE NAME]); 

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

I have verified permission on that file and the entire folder hierarchy up. I have even given everyone full access to test. I used server name, FQDN, IP address, etc. I also verified my session is using KERBEROS.

Any other ideas?

[image: Access denied error in ProcMon]

Comment: What about [PageName$] ? (a '$' at the end of the sheet name)

Comment: You say you've given "everyone" access; does that include the SQL Server Service Account?

Comment: Yes, everyone as in literally the Everyone group, which would include anonymous as well. And I explicitly gave the SQL Server engine service account access as well, but from my screenshot, SQL is passing my kerberos foy my own account, so that shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Did you install the driver on your local pc as well where you are running SSMS from?

Comment: I bet that you're SQL Server is running as `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` isn't it? If so, that's you're problem. it won't be able to access a network share; even one open to "everyone"

Comment: @Larnu No, its an Active Directory service account.

Comment: What are the properties of the provider set to? Did you check `Allow inprocess`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Yes, I tried with both on AND off. Some people said it worked for them different ways so I tried them all. But it works locally, so not sure if that would make a difference if it works one way and not the other. Like I say, it appears to be a permission issue since I am getting access denied.

Comment: I've found that UNC paths don't work. Can you move the file to the SQL Server itself in a test folder and see if that works? If not, have your network admin create that path as a hidden share for you to reference. That will work.

Comment: Microsoft Office programs hold exclusive locks on their documents while open, preventing other programs from accessing them. Your Access Denied error may not be due to Access Control Lists but because somebody has the document open in Excel.